# Cordova Plugin filepickerIo API Key is Missing

Tags: cordova, mobile, filepicker.io

I've used cordova plugin filepickerio but after I implemented it. It shows me "API Key" is missing. May I know how to get API Key for cordova plugin filepicker io.

I tried to create a key at my own but the issue was still exist. I'm not sure if the key was provided by the plugin or I am the who will create a key.

Here's my code:

```
        window.filepicker.setKey('l5uQ3k7FQ5GoYCHyTdZV');
        window.filepicker.setName('MyApp');
        window.filepicker.pick({
            multiple: true,
            mimeTypes: ['image/*', 'application/pdf'],
            services : [ 'CAMERA', 'GALLERY', 'GOOGLE_DRIVE', 'DROPBOX', 'BOX', 'SKYDRIVE'],
            maxFiles: 20,
            maxSize: (10*1024*1024)
        }, function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }, function(e) {
           console.error(e);
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with backbone... please only use relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are currently using the documentation key of: l5uQ3k7FQ5GoYCHyTdZV, have you been able to create your own API Key by signing up as of yet?
You will need to create an account here: https://dev.filestack.com/register/free in order to receive your free API Key.